# ASP.NET Dropdrownlist croaks with SelectValue Assignment

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

This is my aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="DSCategories" runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="GetCategories" TypeName="BAL.CategoryBAL">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

    <div id="Criteria">
        <h3>Category:</h3>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategories" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="DSCategories" DataTextField="Description" 
            DataValueField="Code">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSetCriteria" runat="server" Text="Set Criteria" />

    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

And this is briefly my Page_Load code:

```
SearchCriteriaBAL scb = SearchCriteriaBAL.GetSearchCriteria(id);

string cat = String.Empty;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(scb.Criteria))
{
    cat = ParseCriteria(scb.Criteria);

    ddlCategories.SelectedValue = cat;
}
```

I break on the SelectedValue assignment line and see the items in the dropdownlist and I see a valid value for cat and it is in the list but I get:

> 'ddlCategories' has a SelectedValue
>   which is invalid because it does not
>   exist in the list of items. Parameter
>   name: value

**It seems to be doing the GetCategories AFTER I set the selectedValue and then it dies.**

I placed it on its own test page for fear of interaction but it still fails.  Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the function on DropDownList's DataBound event instead of Page_Load

> Occurs after the server control binds
>   to a data source.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategories" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="DSCategories" 
    DataTextField="Description" 
    DataValueField="Code"
    OnDataBound="ddlCategories_DataBound">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Rather than using `SelectedValue`, I would have opted

```
ddlCategories.Items.FindByValue(cat.Trim()).Selected = true;
```

Comment: I just tried this - it makes sense.  But even though the cat value is in the list, and the list is populated, I get a Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Ohhh - I found it - I had a space at the end of the cat value and it was not finding it in the list. So sorry for everyone's time and help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could try selecting the item this way:

```
ddlCategories.Items.FindByValue(cat).Selected = true;
```

Which of course wont' work if `cat` really isn't in the `Items` collection

Comment: I get a Nullreferenceexception